# How do I solve the condition has length > 1 in Alleleretain

Tags: r

When attempting to run the R package Alleleretain, I keep getting this error message:
Error in if (class(juveniles) != "matrix") juveniles <- as.matrix(rbind(juveniles),  :
the condition has length > 1

I have not named any object 'juveniles' but I think this may have occured somewhere in the background? Perhaps it is something that is required to be filled in my parameters

So far I have been trying to create an object called juveniles that functions as a vector but that doesn't really work if I run it inside of the aRetain object

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** there's nothing you can do except waiting for an update in `AlleleRetain` that fixes this issue, or downgrading your R version (which I discourage).

**Long answer:**

In the function `aRetain()` (and probably others in this package), there's an `if` condition like this:

```r
if (class(juveniles) != "matrix")
```

If the object  `juveniles` only had one class only, this would have been fine because it would have returned a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. However, if `juveniles` has more than 1 class, then `class(juveniles) != "matrix"` will return a vector of logical values. For example:

```r
juveniles <- 1:3
class(juveniles) <- c("some_class", "another_class")

class(juveniles) != "matrix"
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
```

**Why is this a problem?**

Since R 4.2.0, R returns an error if the condition inside an `if()` statement only returns one logical value (before it only returned a warning). This is to avoid ambiguity (if an `if()` statement contains a `TRUE` *and* a `FALSE`, should it be `TRUE` or `FALSE`?).

**What would be the solution?**

This `if()` statement could be fixed by the package developer by using `inherits()` instead, that checks that an object has a specific class among its classes. Using the example from above:

```r
juveniles <- 1:3
class(juveniles) <- c("some_class", "another_class")

!inherits(juveniles, "matrix")
#> [1] TRUE
```